# "At no extra cost" vs "with no extra cost"

Tags: word-choice

Usage:

*Procedure A can thus be applied at/with no extra cost.*

Which is the correct preposition here?

Comment: I'd prefer *at*, but it doesn't make a difference either way. You could try pulling up a Google nGram to see if one is overwhelmingly more popular than the other.

Comment: I tried Ngram but it came back empty: https://goo.gl/asL7mN. If they are interchangeable, could you say that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ah, that's because, unlike regular Google, you don't need to quote phrases. Anything separated by commas is considered an atomic phrase. Try this instead: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+no+extra+cost%2C+with+no+extra+cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20no%20extra%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20no%20extra%20cost%3B%2Cc0.

Comment: Did not know that, thank you! Using "at" is by far the preferred choice, I see. Care to put this info in the form of an answer?

Comment: And I'm very glad to learn you tried searching nGrams first. It's worth telling us what you tried, even if it didn't work, when you ask the question. It'll improve the reception to your question, and get you better, faster answers (because at least we'll know what avenues have already been explored).

Comment: Thanks Dan, next time I'll add my search to the body of the question.

Comment: I am running off to work now, and don't have time to answer, but feel free to add an answer of your own! You'll get rep (I have rep, so I don't need it).

Comment: For my ears, "at no extra cost" is the language of retail, and "with no extra cost" is a less mercantile phrasing. The latter is something I might say if I was explaining some service to a friend, but I wouldn't expect to see it in advertising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dan Bron who clarified that both prepositions can be used, and taught me the correct use of the [NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

[According to that tool](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20no%20extra%20cost%2C%20with%20no%20extra%20cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20no%20extra%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20no%20extra%20cost%3B%2Cc0), "*at*" is by far the most used preposition:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Un my opinion i think 'at no cost ' is more commonly used un British English un particular  when we talk about 'financial cost. While 'with nom cost' may refer to 'saving efforts or risks'

Comment: Your answer reads to some extent as though you wrote it on a cell phone equipped with French auto-correct. Are you satisfied with the spelling?